# Laravel reporting errors

Tags: php, laravel

When Laravel throw an error it show me a page with the description of error pointing me in what file is located the error, in this page are a link with this format

subl://open?url=file://home/user/etc

I know that the goal is open the file with sublime text but it doesn't work.
I would like to know how to configure firefox in order to be able to open the file.
My  working environment  is laravel whith ubuntu 12 
Firefox 35.01
and Sublime text 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done by registering a new protocol handler for the browser.  In Firefox the process is discussed [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Register_protocol) for a myriad of Firefox versions and operating systems.  In your specific case (FF 3.5+ on Linux), it can be done via this procedure:

> **Firefox 3.5 and above**
>   *(Works without installed Gnome libraries)*
>
> - Type about:config into the Location Bar (address bar) and press Enter.
> - Right-click -> New -> Boolean -> Name: `network.protocol-handler.expose.foo` -> Value -> false *(Replace foo with the protocol you're specifying)*
> - Next time you click a link of protocol-type foo you will be asked which application to open it with.